# Updating input field dynamically javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have my add and remove functions as follows:

```
function AddOtherRefDoc(name, number) {
  var remove = "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='removeRefDoctor(this)'>Remove</a>";
  var html = "<li><b> Referral Doctor: </b>"+name+"<b>, Referral No: </b>"+number+ " " +remove+"</li>";
opener.jQuery("#r_docs").append(jQuery(html));
}

function removeRefDoctor(el) { 
var el = jQuery(el);
if (el) { el.parent().remove(); }
else { alert("Unable to remove recipient."); }
```

}

The removeRefDoctor function removes the current element but my input field doesn't get updated. How can I update the following input fields?

```
<ul id="r_docs" >

<% StringTokenizer rdlist = new StringTokenizer(rd,";");
   StringTokenizer rdnolist = new StringTokenizer(rdohip,";");
   while (rdlist.hasMoreTokens() && rdnolist.hasMoreTokens()) {
     String rd_split = rdlist.nextToken();
     String rdno_split = rdnolist.nextToken();  %>      
<li>Referral Doctor: <%=rd_split%><b>, Referral No: </b><%=rdno_split%> <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='removeRefDoctor(this)'>Remove</a></li>
<%} %>  
<input id="r_doctor" type="hidden" name="r_doctor" size="150" value="<%=rd%>">
<input id="r_doctor_ohip" type="hidden" name="r_doctor_ohip"
                                            size="60" value="<%=rdohip%>">

</ul>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "update the input field"? Are you trying to insert a value into the field?

Comment: @jessegavin - yes I'm trying to inser values into the hidden input field. For example, r_doctor is a string which contains a list of doctors separated by a ";".

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeRefDoctor(el) { 
var el = jQuery(el);
if (el) { 
el.parent().remove(); 
$('#r_doctor').val('');
$('#r_doctor_ohip').val('');
}
else { alert("Unable to remove recipient."); }
```

Comment: but this will delete the entire string which contains a list of doctors...I just want to erase that particular doctor who is removed from the r_doctor string. I hope I didn't confuse you.

Comment: Sapphire than pass the if of that element like $('#r_doctor'+id_to_be_empty).val('');

Comment: @Sapphire you have to create html accordingly to make it work if i got your requirements.

Answer (score -1):

your question is a little bit confusing... but here goes anyways... to insert a value into a hidden field...

html

```
<input id="testInput" type="hidden" />
```

js

```
var dataStr = "element1;element2;element3;element4";
$('#testInput').text(dataStr);
```

Comment: if this input field is in the opener window...am I supposed to do opener.$('#testInput').text(dataStr) ?